# Get correct time zone in SQL 2012 on select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, time, timezone

I need to get this SQL query to output the time in the correct time zone when running the following query.

```
SELECT 
     CAST([StartDateTime] AS time(0)) AS 'time' 
     from appointment
```

When I run this it currently return everything in UTC time and I need EST. I have tried the switchoffset command, and it works, but I only need time to display and not date and time.

Comment: What about to cast date returned by `switchoffset` one more time just to get requied time? And by the way can you show what it is returned and how you used it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(HH,-5,[StartDateTime]) as time) AS 'time'
FROM appointment
```

Comment: This does not take daylight saving time into account.  Remember, part of the year, US Eastern Time follows UTC-4 instead of UTC-5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @appointment TABLE
  (
    id integer,
    StartDateTime datetime
  )

INSERT INTO @appointment SELECT 1, '1/1/2014 13:30'
INSERT INTO @appointment SELECT 2, '1/4/2014 4:00'
INSERT INTO @appointment SELECT 3, '1/6/2014 15:30'
INSERT INTO @appointment SELECT 4, '1/8/2014 23:00'

SELECT 
   CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, StartDateTime), '+01:00') as TIME(0)) as StartDateTime
FROM @appointment
```